# How to declear association from an array in Rails 4 model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We would like to do something like following in a user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  model_names = ['Pets', 'Computers' ]
  model_names.each do |a|
    has_many #{a.to_sym}
  end 
end
```

Is the code above going to work in Rails 4? Or any better way to do that?

Comment: Other than ditching the interpolation and `downcase`ing the symbol, this should be good. `has_many a.downcase.to_sym`

Comment: `@Justin Licata`, should we use a callback such as `after_initialize` for execution of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but rails expects those names to be lowercase, snake-case symbols instead of class names.

You can try [tableize](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveSupport/Inflector/tableize) for that

If you need them to be classnames, you'll need to do something like:

```
 model_names.each do |a|
   has_many a.tableize.to_sym
 end
```

Though TBH I'd go the other way eg:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  model_names = [:pets, :computers ]
  model_names.each do |a|
    has_many a
  end 
end
```

then if you ever needed to use model_names elsewhere use: `model_names.map{|a| a.classify }` with possibly `constantize` to turn it into a real class.

Comment: Also does rails allow  `model_names = [:pets, :computers ]` in model definition? I am not sure about this. Thanks.

Comment: Rails model does allow, as we tested.